# Magento API : How to load customer session by ID

Tags: php, api, magento

I'm working on magento module to log in customer with API.

I can log in customer and get frontend sessionId,
but when I want to load session with this sessionId to check if the customer is already logged in I can't.

Here the API function I used:

```
public function login($email,$password,$storecode){
    $result = array();
    $result['code'] = '';
    $result['messages'] =  '';
    try{
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('customers/session');
        $storemodel = Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($storecode);
        $store_id = $storemodel->getId();
        $websiteId = $storemodel->getWebsiteId();
        if($session->loginByApi($email, $password,$websiteId)){
            $result['code'] = 'SUCCESS';
            $result['sessionId'] = $session->getSessionId();
            $customer = $session->getCustomer();
            $result['customer']= array(
                'customerid' => $customer->getId(),
                'firstname' => $customer->getFirstname(),
                'lastname' => $customer->getLastname(),
            );
        }
    } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
        $result['code'] = 'ERRORS';
        $result['messages'] =  $e->getMessage();
    }
    return $result;
}

public function isloggedin($customerId,$customersessionId ,$storecode){
    if(!isset($storecode)){
        $storecode = 'default';
    }

    Mage::app($storecode, 'store');

    $core_session = Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));
    if($customersessionId != null){
        $core_session->setSessionId($customersessionId);
        $core_session->start('frontend');
    }

    $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));

    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);
    $session->setCustomer($customer);


   if($session->isLoggedIn()){
        $session->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);
        $result['sessionId'] = $session->getSessionId();
    }else{
        $result['logged'] = false;
    }
    return $result;

}
```

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: When you say "can't", what exactly do you mean? `$session` is null, something like that?

Comment: $session is loaded as a visitor not customer logged in and  I get always false with $session->isLoggedIn() method

Comment: Any Solution to check the customer is logged in from session id ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps too much, but this code:

```
Mage::app('2', 'store');
$s = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));
$c = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load(1);
$s->setCustomer($c);

if($s->isLoggedIn()){
    echo $c->getName()." is logged in, session: ".$s->getSessionId().PHP_EOL;
} else {
    echo "not logged in".PHP_EOL;
}
```

Did seem to work for me:

```
John Smith is logged in, session: d3rcgvd56md4u3cfctcvnt2ou6
```

Comment: Mike, in my case I don't know the customer ID. I would like to get it by loading the session with the sessionID

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Session ID, you can get at the data with the following call to the core session singleton:

```
$sessId = 'sn1q4ndvr1kieumsmplhd39n83';
$sess = Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array( 'value' => $sessId ));
```

That will retrieve the session for any user, logged-in or not. From there you can determine whether the session belongs to a customer with a check for the customer object:

```
$sessionCustomerId = $sess->getCustomer()->getId();

if ( $sessionCustomerId ) {
    // yay, they are a customer!
    echo $sessionCustomerId;
}
```

Hope that helps.

---

**Edit**:

You can get the session id from the core session (in a chicken-and-egg style) using `Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getEncryptedSessionId()`

Comment: In reference to `$sessId`, what is this derived from? The frontend cookie value? Because (_frustratingly_) this doesn't work for me. `$sess->getCustomer()` becomes NULL, and I know the value is correct from copying from the inspector...

Comment: @Jester the snippets assumes you have the session id already (note line 1). You can get the id from various places, most likely by iterating over the **var/session** folder and dropping the **sess_** prefix.

Comment: Good catch with the 'value' parameter, but it will only work if the session is not initialized yet.

Comment: Bad Code: if ( $sessionCustomerId = $sess->getCustomer()->getId() ) 
Breaks Rule: Assignment in condition